# How to add column with a certain type of number sequence of

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

There are lots of answers for adding a column to a table with some increment; e.g. start at 1 and increment by 1; e.g. 1, 2, 3 etc.

I need to add a column to tables that starts at 1, and increments by 1, but each number is repeated some number of times before the next number in the sequence.

For example: 100 rows of 1, then 100 rows of 2, etc. until the end of the table.

Comment: Fair comment. I do this in excel but I actually have no clue how to do it in mssql.

Comment: But you done a bunch of research right? What did you come across?

Comment: I couldn’t find much outside of the SEQUENCE feature or updating a table and adding an IDENTITY column. I kind of can’t think of how to even word it for research purposes if it makes sense?

Comment: Do you actually need to store the value or could you compute it when required? Saying a bit more about how you use it could allow for better answers.

Comment: Well I export tables to excel, add a column with a sequence, then  REimport to sql for analysis. It’s some thing I would want to alter the actual table, but I could live with a view. Edit: the use is hard to describe but I need to create a sort of ‘batched’ column to do some analysis for duplicates with various sorts of a source table.

Comment: Could you not modify your process to use a regular sequence? Its not clear why you want that type of sequence.

Comment: Otherwise use an identity column for one column and a computed column which divides the identify value by 100. Or add a new column and run an update on it using `row_number()/100`.

Comment: Ok thank you! I will try these ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Options based on what you have said:

1. Create a view and generate the sequence number using `row_number() over ()/100`
2. Create a regular `identity` column and then create a computed column which is your identity column divided by 100 using integer division.
3. Create a regular `int` column and run a manual update on it using `row_number() over ()/100`.

Comment: Thats OK, you're new, thats why I mentioned it :) did my answer actually allow you to solve your problem? Do revisit your other question too.

Comment: I cannot test until tomorrow. I see to my other query, thanks.

Comment: I've create a dummy table of names, favorite color, and added an id column to keep whatever sort I want intact. Interestingly, using the below (simply your first step, pretty much) gets exactly what I need save for an initial stretch of zeros that are 1 less than 'some number':   SELECT
 ROW_NUMBER () OVER(ORDER BY id)/(some number) AS rn,
 *
FROM dummytbl

Comment: `(row_number() over ()/100) + 1`?

Comment: It gets me 99.9% of the way there and that's basically perfect. Thank again, Dave!! EDIT: Dale, lol sorry, mate, xoxo.